# Search bar disfunctional

Tags: php, javascript, html, searchbar

I have made a small HTML search bar that is supposed to be capable of going to any page within the website. The only problem is, it won't leave that page, and if it does, it says the file is not found. Here is the code I have associated with it so far:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="search">
            <input name="search" >
                <button type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8080/filefolder/<?php echo "'".$_POST[search]."'" ?>'">
                Submit</button>
                   </form>
```

When you type anything into the search bar, and you click submit, the page just reloads and empties the search bar which is really frustrating.

So this is all that I have associated with the current search bar. What exactly am I doing wrong with it? I even added JavaScript telling the search button to send it to the page typed out. Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Try drawing a little flow chart of what happens to the text in the input when the user press 'search'. Maybe take a peak at the page source while you do it.

Comment: What do you mean "it won't leave the page?"

Comment: @ExplosionPills the user won't be taken to their wanted destination and the page will stay the same

Answer (score 3):

Your code includes extra quotes which I don't believe you intended to have.

For example:
`http://localhost:8080/filefolder/<?php echo "'".$_POST[search]."'" ?>'">`

Is resulting in:
`http://localhost:8080/filefolder/'search''">`

As you can see this will break the javascript syntax when it tries to read that string.

Rewrite it as:

`http://localhost:8080/filefolder/<?php echo $_POST['search'] ?>'">`

Also add a `return false` to the end.

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='value_for_url'; return false;" />
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but when you press submit, it still stays on the same page. Do you think this is a JavaScript problem?

Comment: your `$_POST['search']` needs to be populated. Double check the value if its set.